# RAM is dying. Could the power supply be the cause?

Tags: memory, power-supply, hardware-failure

I was playing on my old PC when the Blue screen happened and my PC restarted. After that it froze and there was no way to recover it except to force it to shut down.

My screen didn't show anything after I turned it on, so I realized one of my RAM modules had died.

A similar thing happened about 5-6 months ago.

Both dead RAMs were pretty old (5-6 years), but what I would like to know is could it have been caused by my power supply or did I just have bad luck?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost definitely not PSU related - your motherboard filters power before it gets to the RAM, so is more likely the motherboard, or just bad luck.

Comment: Should i buy a new motherboard or it's repairable? can it be my RAM slot?